# Postgres Error Handling in Pentaho Transformation

Tags: postgresql, pentaho-data-integration

I have a Pentaho mapping in which I am loading the data from a flat file to postgres table. Its a simple one to one mapping.

I am trying to incorporate error handling in that mapping.
Without error handling, the data loads pretty fast (speed around 3000 rps) but if error handling is added then it loads the data very slow with speed 1 rps.

Anyone faced this similar problem? Does postgres driver in PDI does not support error handling?

Attaching image of my mapping:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what this error handling does, but I guess it's switching from batched inserts to single-row inserts with savepoints which is expected to be much slower.

Comment: Error handling records all those records which are rejected by database due to constraints. For e.g.: if target table has a primary key and you are supplying the duplicate data then the rejected row will be captured in Error Handling output and the remaining data will be loaded without any errors.